# Installing an event filter and implenmenting mouseMoveEvent does not enable tracking cursor position

Tags: c++, qt, eventfilter, mousepress

I am trying to implement in my program, that if the mouse hovers over my QChartView widget, I get back the coordinates of the cursor.

I already tried, by installing an event filter on the widget:

```
ui->chartView->setMouseTracking(true);
ui->chartView->installEventFilter(this);
```

and then writing the method for a mouse event:

```
void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
    qDebug() << event->pos();
}
```

But, I only get the output when I click on the Mainwindow and hold the mouse button, which I clicked. When I click on the widget `chartView`, I don't get any output.

I need to get output, when the mouse is hovering over `chartview`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an event filter. You need to reimplement the methods [`QWidget::enterEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#enterEvent) and [`QWidget::leaveEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#leaveEvent).

`enterEvent()` is called when the mouse enters the widget and `leaveEvent()` when it leaves it again.

Answer (score 0):

Installing an event filter means you want to customize event handling inside [QObject::eventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#eventFilter), so reimplementing `mouseMoveEvent` goes against the point of using an event filter.

So you do not get output because you have not reimplemented the `eventFilter`, and `mouseMoveEvent` does not get triggered unless you do [setMouseTracking(true);](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop).

Supposing that `this` is `MainWindow`, here is an example reimplementation of `eventfilter`:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        qDebug() << event->pos();
    }
}
```

**Note:** if you install your `mainWindow` as an event filter for multiple objects, you need to check the object as well before customizing the event handling, to avoid undesired behavior.

Example:

```
if(event->type == QEvent::MouseMove && obj->objectName() == "yourObjectName")
```

Or

```
if(event->type == QEvent::MouseMove && qobject_cast<QChartView*>(obj) == ui->chartView)
```